# readonly with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

i'm trying to add readonly to all the inputs and then on the click remove the readonly to make it works for typing.
the readonly set for all inputs part works but the remove on click doesn't work please help.

my code :

```
<script language="javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{
$('#secureFields :input').attr('readonly', true);

    $('.readonly').click(
    function()
    {
        if ($('.readonly').attr("readonly") == true)
        {
            $('.readonly').val('');
            $('.readonly').removeAttr("readonly");
        }           
    }); 
});
</script>
```

html is like this :

```
 <table class='table' id='secureFields'  >
        <tr>
            <td width=200>First Name:</td>
            <td><input readonly='readonly'  type='text'  name='firstname' size=30 class='required'/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
```

Comment: important note: don't write `language="javascript"` but `type="text/javascript"`

Comment: Try it like this `if ($('.readonly').attr('readonly') == 'readonly')`

Comment: to prevent auto fill tools, want the user to insert those fields manually

Comment: That's actually a very good idea..

Comment: I don't see any element with _class_ `readonly`, but your JS code repeatedly selects elements with `.readonly`. Attribute `readonly` != class `readonly`; are you sure you don't mean `[readonly]` in your selectors instead of `.readonly`?

Comment: This is good idea, just keep in mind that users can navigate through fields with `tab` key

Comment: yes, sorry , the class is readonly, i pasted wrong the class

Comment: Thank you all for the helping :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

important note: don't write `language="javascript"` but `type="text/javascript"`

You have to select the inputs with `attribute` readonly, not `class` readonly.

So do the following:

```
$('input[readonly]').click(
```

instead of

```
$('.readonly').click(
```

and then you just need one line:

```
$(this).removeProp("readonly");
```

This is the correct code:

```
$('input[readonly]').click(function(){
     $(this).removeProp("readonly");           
});
```

Check out the **[Examplefiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aWbTE/1/)**

FYI: Script are not stopped by your `readonly`, they can simply set the value of the field...

Comment: @Abude check out the example. It works. Perhaps there is something else wrong with your code.

Comment: @Abude important note: You need jQuery version 1.7 to make this work! (Else you have to use `removeAttr`)

Comment: @Abude Then you are doing something wrong somewhere else in your code...Show us the rest of your code. And check the webdeveloper console (F12) if there are any errors.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12476/discussion-between-christoph-and-abude)

Comment: i have : jQuery JavaScript Library v1.6.2

Comment: can you help me with this mate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188573/how-do-i-separate-my-urls-in-textarea-by-rows-jquery thanks!

Answer (score 9):

Do you mean:

```
$("input").click(function() {
  if ( $(this).is('[readonly]') ) {
     $(this).removeAttr("readonly");
  } 
});
```

See: [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5gDtt/5/)

Answer (score 4):

```
<html>

 <table class='table' id='secureFields'>
    <tr>
        <td width=200>First Name:</td>
        <td><input type='text'  name='firstname' size=30 class='required'/></td>
    </tr>
</table>

   <button id="btnEnableInputs" type="button">Enable!</button>     

</html>

$(document).ready(function() {

$("#secureFields :input").each(function() {
   $(this).attr("readonly", true);
});

$("#btnEnableInputs").click(function() {
     $("#secureFields :input").each(function() {
          $(this).attr("readonly", false);
     });
 });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/hfK8f/

Comment: @Abude - change $("#btnEnableInputs") to $(".readonly").click

Answer (score 3):

the class you specified is 'required' so `$('.readonly').attr("readonly") == true` should be
`$('.required').attr("readonly") == true` and so on

Comment: yes, i made a mistake in the post, but actually it is .required, but still not working, do i need any thing else like jquery 1.2 ?

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
$('input').click(function() {
   $(this).prop('readonly', false)
});
```

Comment: can you help me with something on this jquery ?

Comment: can we talk on chat ? i can't create one, could you please and type the link here for me to enter ? thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#secureFields :input').attr('readonly', true);
    $('input[readonly]').click(
        function (event) {
        if ($(event.currentTarget).attr("readonly") == "readonly") {
            $(event.currentTarget).removeAttr("readonly");
            $(event.currentTarget).val("");
        }
    });
});
```

this changes attribute readonly on the input that was clicked, hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

```
comment the script part/**/ to check  readonly  mode

<body> 
<table class='table' id='secureFields'  >
        <tr>
            <td width=200>First Name:</td>
            <td><input readonly="readonly"  type='text'  name='firstname' size=30 class='required'/></td>
        </tr>
       </table>

</body>

<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function()
{
$('#secureFields:input').attr('readonly', true);
$('.required').val('');

    $('.required').focus(
    function()
    {
        if ($('.required').attr("readonly") == true)
        {

            $('.required').removeAttr("readonly");
        }           
    }); 
});  
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you want simply:

```
$('#secureFields :input').click(function() {
    $('input[readonly]').val('').removeAttr('readonly');        
});
```

Since there is no `readonly` CSS selector in the HTML, and thus your script does nothing since it references `.readonly`, I have to make assumptions about what you are trying to do.  The above will make all readonly fields non-readonly and clear the current value when any input is clicked.

Answer (score 1):

To prevent autocomplete, you can just add autocomplete="off" in the input tag or the form tag (if set for both, the input value takes precedence, so you can use autocomplete="on" for individual tags.

Anyways, the .selector selects elements with a specific class, not attribute. You can:

Select using the attribute selector: input[readonly] to select inputs where the readonly attribute exists, or input[readonly="readonly"] to select input where the attribute is set to itself (first one being preferred).

In fact, you don't need to select only the inputs which have the attribute set and you can write the following to remove the readonly attribute as soon as it is clicked:

```
$('input').click(function(){
  $(this).removeAttr('readonly')
}
```

Still, you probably just want
    <input autocomplete="off" ...>
all along.

Comment: i want to resolve auto fill, not auto complete, autofill tools saves your info, passwords,data ..etc , and then with only one fill it types all your fields...